# Object doesn't support this property or method IE8 hasclass method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a Object doesn't support this property or method IE8 error at line 7, is there any problem with the hasclass method? or what is wrong? Thanks-

```
function LoadProducts()
{
    var rangeProduct = 0;
    var type = new Array();
    $('.menu_products .range li').each(function()
    {
        if((this).hasClass('select'))
        {
            rangeProduct = ($(this).index() +1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are missing the `$` before `(this)`. Your code is equivalent to `this.hasClass(...)` and DOM elements really don't have a `hasClass` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `$`.

```
if((this).hasClass('select'))
```

Should be this:

```
if($(this).hasClass('select'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$(this)`, not `(this)`.

It's a jQuery function and that code shouldn't work in any browser.